# md5 error for follow_joint_trajectory/result topic between matlab and ros indigo

Tags: ros, matlab, md5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a 7-dof manipulator being simulated in the gazebo. Now I am trying to move it through follow_joint_trajectory action interface in matlab.
When I send the goal after creating the actionclient, seven_dof_arm/seven_dof_arm_joint_controller/follow_joint_trajectory, the model in the gazebo succeeds in moving to the desired pose. But then some error appears in the terminal. It is shown as follow.

```
[ERROR] [1479176827.080220708, 3.214000000]: Client [/matlab_global_node_16201] wants topic /seven_dof_arm/seven_dof_arm_joint_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result to have datatype/md5sum [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult/bce83d50f7bb28226801436caf0e2043], but our version has [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult/c4fb3b000dc9da4fd99699380efcc5d9]. Dropping connection.
```

As it shows, the md5sum of message control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult in matlab and ros indigo are different. How to fix this error?
Thanks very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248112/md5-error-for-follow_joint_trajectory/result-topic-between-matlab-and-ros-indigo/) by [TyrionZK](https://answers.ros.org/users/28530/tyrionzk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a question that has been asked quite often:
http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:md5/page:1/

Long story short, either the message/service/action definition on the different PCs (I'm assuming you are running this on different PCs) is different (note that they need to be exactly the same) or you are mixing ROS distributions whicht could lead to md5 differences due to changes to the code generation.

Make sure you are using the same ROS distro, make sure you have the same message/service/action definition and **recompile** if you change them

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TyrionZK](https://answers.ros.org/users/28530/tyrionzk/) on 2016-11-15**:
Thanks for your time. I see your point.
While I can update my packages by executing the command "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-control-msgs --reinstall", how can I update the message definition in the matlab2016b? I am not able to find the message/service/action definition in the matlab.